# pyplot: loglog contour with labels fix angle

Tags: matplotlib, plot

This is an extension of a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51717394/7042795).

I intend to make a contour plot, with labeled contours, then change the axes scales to 'log'.

This works fine except that the rotation of the contour labels is not adjusted. Can this be fixed?

```
loglog = False

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = (np.linspace(0, 10))
y = (np.linspace(0, 10))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
C = plt.contour(X, Y, np.sqrt(X) * Y)
plt.clabel(C, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.xlim(1, 10)
plt.ylim(1, 10)
if loglog: plt.xscale('log')
if loglog: plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

The fist plot is obtained with `loglog=False` in the second `loglog=True`:

[image: non-logarithmic plot]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is actually obvious. Changing the the axes scale types in advance helps, of course.

**Edit:**
I think it makes sense  to use logspace instead of linspace here.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.logspace(0, 1, 100, base=10)
y = np.logspace(0, 1, 100, base=10)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
plt.xlim(1, 10)
plt.ylim(1, 10)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
C = plt.contour(X, Y, np.sqrt(X) * Y)
plt.clabel(C, inline=1, fontsize=10)
```

[image]